# How to turn off Windows caching on a container file?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, cache, veracrypt

For a regular disk/partition, it's easy to [turn off caching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/turn-disk-write-caching-on-off) (useful in the case of an external HDD: you don't want to postpone writing).

[image]

But in the case of a Veracrypt encrypted container file `H:\container.bin` mounted as `I:\`, doing the above setting on `H:\` doesn't have any effect on `I:\`.

I did extensive tests, and I confirm `I:\` still has caching on:

- I obtain write speeds of several hundreds of MB/s for 500MB to 1GB files, impossible with my USB3 HDD connected on a *USB2* plug
- also when unmounting the device, I had to wait 1 minute - the flushing was done *at this time*

**How to force automatic flushing to disk (non-caching) on a virtual disk / Veracrypt container?**

Indeed, there is no "hardware device" associated to `I:\` in the device manager, so you cannot do the above setting to `I:\`. You can do it for the host disk `H:\`, but it does not have any effect on `I:\`.

I already tried [sync.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync), it works, but I don't want to have to do this manually after each write operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an internal Veracrypt problem, as mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/709).